# JUnit Parameterized - merge fails

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, parameterized, test-runner

**Background:**

Our Test-Suite uses an inhouse developed Test-Framework, based on JUnit. Several of our tests use JUnit's Parameterized functionality in order to test the variety of different test data, e.g. layout tests (we use Galen Framework), where we want to verify the correct behaviour at diferrent window resolutions.

Our TestCaseRule, which is applied to all of our tests in a base class, saves the failed tests into a Database, from there we can browse through the fails by a Web Interface.

**Problem:**

JUnit's Parameterized Runner creates one fail instance for each failed test + parameter combination.

That means, if I have a class with for instance 3 tests, and each one runs 6 times (6 parameters), if all tests fail I would get 6x3=18 fails in my reporting, instead of (desired) 3. Thereby our reporting gets an entire different meaning and becomes useless...

**Desired:**

I have googled a lot but unfortunately could not find anyone facing the same issue. The best solution for me would be if I could get JUnit to merge all fails per method and concatenating stacktraces, so I could really just ensure one method will result at the most in 1 fail. I also do not want to skip all following tests, so I don't miss fails which would be generated on different parameters.

I experimented with reflection; fetching Parameters data in a @Before method, iterating through the test method, injecting the parameters and finally preveting the actual test to be executed, but it was quite hacky and did not represent an accceptable solution because of its test-scope-lack.

---

I am thankful for all help attempts!